# Random forest vs Regression behaviour

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, random-forest, decision-tree

I am trying to predict the users intent of performing a click. So, I tried two approached RandomForest and LinearRegression using sklearn library in Python.

Regression :

```
 from sklearn import linear_model
    linreg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

RandomForest :

```
 from sklearn import ensemble
    forest = ensemble.RandomForestRegressor()
    forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Output of regression :

[image]

Output of RandomForest :

[image]

As you can see for the same set of feature sets and the same data results of both the models are very different. Moreover, the importance of each feature sets in both model is different and their relative importance is also different. So, can anyone explain this behavior? It looks to me that Regression is doing a pretty good job in segregating the zeros with non-zeros, right?

Comment: Could you explain what is going on in your output?

Comment: I am just trying to predict the user's action whether he will perform both 1 & 2 or it will only perform 1. So, at the last column percentage which you see it basically `countOf2/ TotalCount`.